# Truncate label text from the left

Tags: xamarin.forms, right-to-left

I have a Label that displays the full name and path of the file that the app is currently processing.

The way `Label`s perform text truncation, the "C:\..." part of the path is always shown, while the actual file name is only shown if it fits. I would rather truncate on the left side, so that the file name is always shown, while the "C:\..." part is only shown if it fits.

Is this possible in Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#truncation-and-wrapping) these are the options for truncation

- HeadTruncation – truncates the head of the text, showing the end.
- CharacterWrap – wraps text onto a new line at a character boundary.
- MiddleTruncation – displays the beginning and end of the text, with the middle replace by an ellipsis.
- NoWrap – does not wrap text, displaying only as much text as can fit on one line.
- TailTruncation – shows the beginning of the text, truncating the end.
  WordWrap – wraps text at the word boundary.

**HeadTruncation** appears to be what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you! Did not think to check the LineBreakMode property for this. I was looking at HorizontalTextAlignment and HorizontalOptions and even researched right-to-left language support.